# how to select time from datetime datatype in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select orders which were shipped after 2 pm and this code gives me the wrong result

`select order_id, ship_date from orders
where ship_date >= '%y-%m-%d 14%-%-%';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select order_id, ship_date from orders where HOUR(ship_date) >= 14
```